# Help with notations - integrating w.r.t. f(dx)

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I am reading an economic theory paper *(Doval, L., & Skreta, V. (2022). Mechanism design with limited commitment. Econometrica, 90(4), 1463-1500.)* and the authors use some integration notations I'm not very familiar about.

For example in Definition 1, the authors write:
$$\varphi(\tilde{U} \times \tilde{A}|\theta) = \int_\tilde{U}\alpha(\tilde{A}|\mu)\beta(du|\theta)$$

My main confusion is that the $du$ part is inside a function $\beta(.|\theta)$, and I don't have the mathematical knowledge to interpret that. Or in general, what does $\int f(x)g(dx)$ mean? How would one evaluate it?

Some contexts here that may (or may not) help:

- $\Theta$ is an event space
- $A$ is a non-empty set
- $\tilde{U} \subset \Delta(\Theta)$ and $\tilde{A} \subset A$
- $\beta$ and $\varphi$ are probability functions conditional on some $\theta\in \Theta$:

  - $\beta:\Theta\to\Delta(\Delta(\Theta))$
  - $\varphi:\Delta(\Delta(\Theta)\times A)$
- $\alpha$ is a probability function conditional on some $\mu\in \Delta(\Theta)$:

  - $\alpha:\Delta(\Theta)\to\Delta(A)$

I can intuit that $\beta(du|\theta)$ could mean the marginal probability of a particular $\mu \in \Delta(\Delta(\Theta))$ being realised, conditional on some $\theta\in\Theta$, as I increase $u \in \tilde{U} \subset \Delta(\Theta)$ marginally. By that, I could read the overall meaning of the integral. But if someone gives me an example with the explicit functional forms, I would not know how to evaluate the integral. I'd appreciate it so much if someone with more fluency in this notation could guide me through that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In general, if $\mu$ is a measure on a measurable space $\mathcal{X}$, then $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$$ stands for the integral of a function $f$ with respect to the measure $\mu$. In this notation, $\mathrm{d}x$ symbolizes a generic, infinitesimal subregion of $\mathcal{X}$. This is motivated by the observation that, *heuristically*, the integral is the limit of a Riemann-sum-like quantity: $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)=\text{“limit of }\sum_{i\in I}f(x_i)\,\mu(E_i)\text{”}$$ where $\{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{X}$ and $x_i \in E_i$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks! Your Riemann-esque explanation is super helpful. A followup if you will: if it represents an integration with respect to some measure $\mu$, would it convey the same meaning if I write $\int f(x) d \mu (x)$? In fact, that's an integral I've seen some authors do write (e.g. Kamenica, E., & Gentzkow, M. (2011). Bayesian persuasion. American Economic Review, 101(6), 2590-2615. - definition of Bayes-plausibility). Or is there a subtle difference I'm missing?

Comment: It is indeed more or less a matter of flavor, as they convey the same meaning. There are many variants of the notation for abstract Lebesgue integral, such as $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x), \qquad \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x), \qquad \int_{\mathcal{X}} f \, \mathrm{d}\mu, \qquad \mu(f), \qquad \text{etc.}$$